# Uncaught TypeError: Event is not a constructor

Tags: tabulator

I have tried a variety of methods of getting my JSON data object into tabulator.

Converting HTML to Tabulator is what I was trying to do.

My ajax query returns a lot more data than needed for the table. Also I am using WordPress with my own plugin handling the ajax query, if there are specifics I need.

```
jQuery.ajax({
             action:  'purchase_order_query',
             type:    "GET",
             url:     myAjax.ajaxurl,
             data:    reportdata,
             success: function(data) {
                //Converts string into javascript array object
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    len = data.length;
                //checks for what type of report before creating table. changed to Case basis instead   
                //make sure to add before loop table headers inside the dynamic table.

                switch(MostValuableVariable){ //add a switch for sorting data out of object and creating table.
                    case 'Employee': 
                      /*  var table = new Tabulator("#TabulatorTable", {
                            height:205,
                            data:data,
                            layout:"fitColumns",
                            columns:[
                                {title:"Employee Submitted", field:"Ordered"},
                                {title:"Employee Approved", field:"Approved"},
                                {title:"Date Submitted", field:"Date", sorter:"date"},
                                {title:"Payment Method", field:"Payment"},
                                {title:"Vender", field:"Vender"},
                            ],
                        });
                      */  console.log(data);







                 jQuery("#usertable").html("");
                    jQuery("#usertable").html("<tbody class='usertable'></tbody>")
                    var str_str = "<tr class='mainboi usertable'>" +
                   // "<th style='width:10%;' class='usertable' align='center'>" + "LAA Order ID Number" + "</th>" +
                    "<th style='width:5%;' align='center'>" + "emp" + "</th>" +
                    "<th style='width:10%;' align='center'>" + "date" + "</th>" +
                    "<th align='center'>" + "Payment" + "</th>" +
                    "<th style='width:40%;' align='center'>" + "Vender" + "</th>" +
                    "<th align='center'>" + "Approved" + "</th>" +
                    "</tr>";
                //this part of the code finds table and creates shabby headers
                    jQuery("#usertable tbody").append(str_str);
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    console.log(data[i]);
                    var emp = data[i].Ordered;
                    var date = data[i].Date
                    var Payment = data[i].Payment;
                    var Vender = data[i].Vender;
                    var Approved = data[i].Approved;
                    var OrderID = data[i].OrderID;
                    //this part of the code makes the table.
                    var tr_str = "<tr class='mainboi usertable' id='" + OrderID + "'>" +
                        //"<td  class='usertable' align='left'>" + OrderID + "</td>" +
                        "<td  class='usertable' align='left'>" + emp + "</td>" +
                        "<td  class='usertable' align='left'>" + date + "</td>" +
                        "<td  class='usertable' align='left'>" + Payment + "</td>" +
                        "<td  class='usertable' align='left'>" + Vender + "</td>" +
                        "<td  class='usertable' align='left'>" + Approved + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";
                    //this part of the code finds the usertable and selects the <tbody> and adds the above information to the end on loop.
                        jQuery("#usertable tbody").append(tr_str);
                     }
                     var table = new Tabulator("#usertable",{});
                break;
                case 'OrderID': //use this to query and show ORDER ID queries
                slingo = dingo + 100000;
                console.log(slingo);
                if (jQuery("tr[id^="+slingo+"]").length > 0){
                    console.log("Duplicate Detected");
                    jQuery("."+slingo).remove();
                    jQuery("tr[id^="+slingo+"]").remove();
                }
                else if(slingo < 999999999999){
                    var str_str = "<tr class='ahhh ' id='" + slingo + "'>" +
                        "<th  class='usertable' align='center'>" + "Description" + "</th>" +
                        "<th class='usertable' align='center'>" + "ItemCost" + "</th>" +
                        "<th class='usertable' align='center'>" + "QTY" + "</th>" +
                        "</tr>";
                    //this part of the code finds table and creates shabby headers
                        jQuery("tr[id^="+dingo+"]").after(str_str);
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    //console.log(data[i]);
                    var description = data[i].Description;
                    var cost = data[i].ItemCost
                    var qty = data[i].QTY;
                    //this part of the code makes the table.
                    var tr_str = "<tr class='miniscream " + slingo + "'>" +
                        "<td class='usertable' align='left'>" + description + "</td>" +
                        "<td class='usertable' align='left'>" + cost + "</td>" +
                        "<td class='usertable'  align='left'>" + qty + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";
                    //this part of the code finds the usertable and selects the <tbody> and adds the above information to the end on loop.
                    jQuery("tr[id^="+slingo+"]").after(tr_str);
                       
                     }
                }
                break;
                case 'Date':

                break; 
                    }
            
        }
        
    });
}
```

As you can maybe tell, I'm very new to all of this. When it runs it was working exactly as expected- having now added the Tabulator portion it give the error "Uncaught TypeError: Event is not a constructor"

Comment: Have not been able to solve this, Went to Datatables instead.

Answer (score 1):

I meet this problem ,but the issue is not bacause tabulator ,the reason is that my wabapp has a component changed "Event" object , you can search in file folder "window.Event", maybe is useful for you